# HTML5 Builder change client mobile page

Tags: rad, html5builder

I've just downloaded a trial of HTML5 Builder and have created a number of client mobile pages. I assumed there was a way to switch which client mobile page is currently being displayed in my test app but can't find how to do this. Was this an incorrect assumption?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I'm writing this question up on behalf of a friend. This was mistagged as RAD Studio XE3 but is actually HTML5 builder. Many apologies, and thanks for raising the point so quickly

Answer (score 2):

You can switch pages with **links** between pages.

For example, if your main page is called *unit1.js*, and you want to be able to go from there to *unit2.js*, add to *unit1.js* a link to *unit2.php*. (*Is not a typo, links must point to the .php file, they are then fixed during the mobile deployment process*)

To create a link, you can use for example the **MLink** component, and write the target page on its *Link* property.

Comment: Brilliant! We couldn't find that anywhere. Thank you *so much* !